# XSLT - How can I get all characters inside a string

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml that I created with the following template and function:

```
<xsl:variable name='documents' select="collection('xml')"></xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:function name="kw:listChars">
                <xsl:param name="textString"></xsl:param>
                   <xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(
                       distinct-values(
                            string-to-codepoints(
                                string-join($textString,'')
                             )
                       )
                   )"/>
        </xsl:function>
<xsl:template match="/">
            <text>
            <xsl:for-each select="$documents">
            
            <xsl:value-of select="kw:listChars(//text())"/>
            
            </xsl:for-each>
                </text>
</xsl:template>
```

I receive an xml that contains a  node.
How can I get every single character in a `<li>`

For the first substring I can use the function on `(substring(text(), 1,1)`.

I am probably looking for sth. like  a `<xsl:for-each select="substring()"/>`

Any hints?
All the best

Comment: It is not clear what the problem is exactly, "get every single character in a `<li>`", as a plain string value is simply `string(li)` or `string()` if the `li` in XSLT is the context node already.

Comment: Ah, fu.. not enough coffee :-D I want the string inside <text> to be split after each character So if I have ```<text> Hello world </text>``` I want ```<li>H</li> <li>e</li> .... ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just want (XSLT 3 with `expand-text="yes"` in place):

```
  <xsl:template match="text">
      <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints(.) ! codepoints-to-string(.)[normalize-space()]">
              <li>{.}</li>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

or XSLT 2

```
  <xsl:template match="text">
      <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="for $c in string-to-codepoints(.) return codepoints-to-string($c)[normalize-space()]">
              <li>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </li>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: nice, thanks ... I fooled around some time and came up with the same XSLT 2 :) 
First step done :-D